# how to call different settings from manage.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-manage.py

I'm trying to call environment specific settings in django.

I found that you can do something close in django admin according to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility

I tried this with the manage.py:

```
python3 manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.prod_settings
```

I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings.prod_settings';
>   'mysite.settings' is not a package

How can I call environment specific settings?

Thanks

Comment: Is `__init__.py` included inside `mysite/settings/` ?

Comment: Aw good point.  my file is called prod_settings.py , I need to remove settings

Answer (score 5):

I changed the command to:

python3 manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.prod_settings

because I have a file called prod_settings.py  and it worked.